# Nginx does not cache cross domain requests (CORS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have rails application and nginx.

There are parts of the nginx config:

```
http {
    ...
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels= keys_zone=cache:50m inactive=1d;
    ...
}

server {
    ...
    location @rails {
        proxy_pass http://rails_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 300m;

        proxy_cache cache;
        proxy_cache_valid 1h;

        set $proxy_hide_header 'Set-Cookie';

        proxy_hide_header $proxy_hide_header;
        proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires";
    }
    ...
}
```

I have a promblem with caching cross domain requests.

Cache files are created when I open the url my_domain/data.js directly.

Cache files are created when I open the url my_domain/data.js from my_domain/index.html using ajax request.

Cache files are **not** created when I open the url my_domain/data.js from my_domain2/index.html using ajax request.

Content and http code are ok in all cases.

Comment: Isn't it POST request?

Comment: No, this request is GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in rails (not in nginx). 
Rails add "Set-Cookie" header for cross domain requests even if cookie is already set (I don't know why, maybe it's rails bug).
So my solution is:

```
proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
```